# Django Access File on Server

Tags: python, ios, django, apple-push-notifications

I'm using Django to send iOS push notifications.  To do that, I need to access a .pem certificate file currently stored on the server in my app directory along with views.py, models.py, admin.py, etc.  When I try to send a push notification from a python shell on the server, everything works fine.  But when I try to send a push notification by accessing a Django view, it doesn't send and gives me an SSLError.  I think that this is because Django can't find the .pem certificate file.

In short, I'm wondering how a Django view function can read in another file on the server.

Comment: It can access any files, provided it has valid file permissions. What error do you get? How do you create path and access it? Some sample code will be useful.

Comment: I tried it again using an absolute file path, and it worked after I restarted Django.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I tried it again using an absolute file path, and it worked after I restarted Django.